# Pasting JSON in slack changes some unicode characters to other similar ones...why

Tags: json, unicode, encoding, ascii, codepoint

Copying a simple JSON request body like the following in SLACK throws an error after using it in my request

```
{
   “identifier”:“123abc”,
   “mappings”:[
      {
         “a”: 1,
         “b”: 2,
         “c”: 3
      }
   ]
}
```

I noticed when trying to convert this to ASCII that the '"' character before and after pasting this code in slack was a different unicode codepoint. Is this slacks doing? Or is this some conversion that is happening for them by virtue of their font or something?

" becomes appropriate left and right quotes ” “

Isn't it possible/preferable in most cases for them to save it in the unicode that I specified it in? Wouldn't it be better if a copy action went to the database and retrieved the actual unicode I began with or is this too slow for most people?

Answer (score 0):

It’s a word processor. Word processors tend to use quote characters that are better for word processing. Never pass source code, including JSON, through a word processor.

Comment: Isn't any application that deals with user input a 'word processor'? I know that slack has the ability to display the correct unicode in a code block. I guess I just don't understand the architectural need for it. It seems easier to just let the user copy what was saved... but then I suppose sometimes you do want to steal fonts and what not from somewhere. So guess there is a balance.

Comment: But I still want to know if slack is manually doing the character substitution or whether its handled by virtue of the font they are using doing some automatic substitution.